# When framing stud walls against concrete basement foundation walls, can the frame make direct contact with the moisture barrier?

Tags: basement, framing, moisture, basement-refinishing

I am planning to frame a habitable space in my basement. The basement is poured concrete walls with an exterior DMX foundation wrap. There is also a vapor barrier installed under the slab.

For the walls that will be up against the foundation walls, can the framing make direct contact with the 6 mil moisture barrier that will sit between the concrete and the wood? Or must there be some amount of stand-off in that scenario?

I am also exploring using 1" rigid foam board as the means of moisture control (and part of the insulation solution in that case). Though this would be much more expensive than running 6 mil poly sheet, and I have some space constraints to work within and conform to code.

Thanks.

Comment: Normally (in my region) the moisture barrier goes on the _warm_ side of the wall. Is this barrier a fallback for the foundation wrap or for airborne moisture?

Comment: @isherwood To my knowledge the *moisture* barrier goes on the cold side, between the stud wall and the foundation wall. The *vapor* barrier goes on the warm side. It will be a fallback for the foundation wrap as we have very little water infiltration (but not zero), but also part of the insulation solution.

Comment: Well, vapor _is_ moisture. I didn't realize that you were distinguishing the terms as such.